# Auto-insert soft hyphen in Jekyll Markdown, assuming a specific language?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I'd like to use justified text for my Jekyll-based website, but there are currently some unpleasant gaps in text at various widths. By inserting the soft hyphen character, `&shy;`, into my Markdown, I managed to make it look much better.

However, it is an unpleasant process, and it defeats most of the point of using Markdown. Software packages such as Microsoft Word are capable of inserting hyphens at logical points, presumably based on a dictionary of acceptable break points.

- Where can I get a dictionary of that sort?
- How can I make Jekyll automatically perform this process when processing Markdown text?

I only care about supporting English at this point.

Comment: In most major browsers except Chrome, you can also enable hyphenation with CSS...

Comment: Justified text is less readable than left aligned text. You will have to choose between graphic appearance and readability. And, from my point of view you'd better be readable than graphic.

Comment: @mb21 yeah, Chrome is the #1 browser though

Comment: [Smartypants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/) offers some hyphenation functionality, but I don't think it does a soft hyphen. Perhaps some Smartypants variant addresses this. At least it might give you a few extra search terms.

Comment: you can write some code using [text-hyphen](https://github.com/halostatue/text-hyphen) or similar... (just googled "ruby hyphenation dictionary")

Comment: The [jekyll-hyphenate_filter](https://github.com/grzm/jekyll-hyphenate_filter) plugin seems to do what you're looking for. The project has been archived on 22 Jan 2023, but I guess it still works?

Answer (score -1):

> However, it is an unpleasant process, and it defeats most of the point
>   of using Markdown.

This does not have anything to do with Markdown. This is an HTML issue.

HTML does not hyphenate, unless you use [CSS hyphenation](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/). This has poor browser support and is language dependent (use `hyphenate-resources` for this).

I would accept the spotty browser support of this CSS feature (accept its graceful degredation/progressive enhancement). If that is unacceptable for you, you can use a javascript library, like [hyphenator.js](http://mnater.github.io/Hyphenator/), to insert the `&shy;` characters into your content.